# Dynamic progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need to code a progress bar that's has some custom max width value for the bar and also a custom progress. I found something relavant to the but it's lacking some functionality.

HTML:

```
<div class="meter">
  <span style="width:502px"></span>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.meter {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  /* viewing purposes */
  margin-left: 100px;
  /* viewing purposes */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 #d3d0d0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 #d3d0d0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 #d3d0d0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
div.meter span {
  display: block;
  height: 27px;
  animation: grower 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: grower 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation: grower 1s linear;
  -o-animation: grower 1s linear;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

   background-color:#e8e8e8;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#e8e8e8, endColorstr=#ff8d00);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #ff8d00 46%,#eb0221 100%);
background-image:linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #ff8d00 46%,#eb0221 100%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #ff8d00 46%,#eb0221 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #ff8d00 46%,#eb0221 100%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #ff8d00 46%,#eb0221 100%);
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#e8e8e8), color-stop(46%,#ff8d00),color-stop(100%,#eb0221));}

  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
div.meter span:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}
div.meter p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialised;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

@keyframes grower {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes grower {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes grower {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes grower {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
    $(function(){
        var bar = $('span');
var p = $('p');


var width = "bar.attr('style')";
width = width.replace("width:", "");
width = width.substr(0, width.length-1);


var interval;
var start = 0; 
var end = parseInt(width);
var current = start;

var countUp = function() {
  current++;
  p.html(current + "%");

  if (current === end) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
};

interval = setInterval(countUp, (1000 / (end + 1)));

    });
```

FIDDLE [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/71f687zq/)

The maximum width of the progress bar should be customizable for example 10000
and your progress is 5000. The maximum should be any number inserted on the script. and if its also to display the equal division of the bar by 4. Like the image below. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I tried to generate a dynamic progress bar. You can see the result here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qo8sgwgo/2/)

What I did is the following thing:

- I created a wrapper around the progress bar which contains the specific width of the bar
- I set the progress bar width to 100%, it is easier to set the width of the progress if we have a scale from 0 to 100
- I added jQuery animation effect instead of using keyframe within your CSS
- I set the text and the position of the text below the progress bar dependend on the size of the progress bar itself.

The only thing you want to change is:

```
var end = 75; // Were this value is the position were the bar ends
```

and:

```
.wrapper{width:800px;}
```

If you have any question let me know.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="meter">
      <span></span>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="ticks">        
        <span class="first"></span>
        <span class="second"></span>
        <span class="third"></span>       
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var bar = $('span');
    var p = $('p');

    var width = $(".wrapper").width(); // the width of the wrapper can be set via CSS


    var interval;
    var start = 0; 
    var end = 75; //Percentage were the bar must end (value from 0 to 100)
    var current = start;

    var calculate_percentage = (width / 100) * end

    var countUp = function() {
      current++;
       $('div.meter span').animate({width:end+"%"},11000); // Animation of the progress bar
       p.html(current + "px");

      if (current === calculate_percentage) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    };

    interval = setInterval(countUp, (500 / (end + 1)));
    var first = width / 4;
    var second = first * 2;
    var third = first * 3;
    $(".first").append(first + "px");
    $(".first").css("left", first+"px");
    $(".second").append(second + "px");
    $(".second").css("left", second+"px");
    $(".third").append(third + "px");
    $(".third").css("left", third+"px");    

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's already working. All you have to do is to take the width of the bar, and say, we use 10,000 (as the bar width):

Start with the 0, then display 2500 (10,000/4), then 7500 and finally 10,000.

As for the progress bar itself, just display the number as you're updating it.

--

Also, you should probably use % for the progress bar, because if you use 10,000 as the width, it would take more than the screen size.